# My ISP claims to support IPv6 but I can't get an address. Am I doing something wrong or is it on their end?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ipv6, isp

My ISP is CNS (Community Network Services) in the southern Georgia area. I have contacted both the webmaster and technical support via email and both of them claim that they are IPv6 compliant. Supposedly they have DHCP enabled and as long as I configure my router correctly, I should receive addresses automatically, but it just doesn't work at all. I am using an ASUS RT-ACRH13 router. My settings are Connection Type: Native, DHCP-PD: Enabled, Auto Config: Stateless, Connect to DNS Server Automatically: Enabled, and Router Advertisement: Enabled.

They didn't give me any setup information and by the wording of their responses, I believe automatic settings should work. The only way I can get IPv6 to work is through a 6in4 tunnel broker, but that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is whether I'm configuring my router wrong or if it's a problem on their end. I emailed them about it but got this generic answer that doesn't help at all: `There is usually an option on the device to turn IPv6 addressing off and on. With DHCP the addresses are randomly assigned so if your device has the compatibility, it may receive and IPv6 address.`

Comment: If your router is able to make a routing table consisting of the IPv6 addresses from your inside-local machines, and if NAT is enabled for IPv6, then you've done all you can do on your end.

Comment: If it's any help, when I go to test-ipv6.com I get the following results: `You appear to be able to browse the IPv4 Internet only. You will not be able to reach IPv6-only sites.

Your IPv6 connection appears to be using Teredo, a type of IPv4/IPv6 gateway; currently it connects only to direct IP's. Your browser will not be able to go to IPv6 sites by name. This means the current configuration is not useful for browsing IPv6 web sites.

Your DNS server (possibly run by your ISP) appears to have IPv6 Internet access.`

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your router not your ISP.

Comment: If you have access to a router that belongs to you, you should be able to line con in and configure IPv6. If the router you're using belongs to your ISP, those settings are likely hidden behind a password (often a "password of the day"). Without configuration settings available in, for example, a terminal for the router's operating system, it's difficult to easily view routing tables as received by each router. You could use software such as WireShark or any packet tracer which will tell you IP addresses used, but routers may still translate IPv6 to IPv4 like you're already seeing.

Comment: I own the router that I'm trying to configure but it's connected to a modem which is owned by the ISP and it does indeed have its settings hidden behind a password so they are inaccessible to me. Now that you mention it, I wonder if it could be the modem which is at fault. I don't think it's my router because I can even connect my computer directly to the modem and I still don't get an IPv6 address. I've even tried power cycling all of the devices with no luck. The only other thing I can think is that maybe they don't issue addresses immediately?

Comment: When you say modem, do you actually mean a 56Kbps CSU/DSU, or is it a layer 3 switch?

Comment: It's a cable internet connection so I'm referring to the box that the coaxial cable plugs into. From that I have an ethernet cable plugged into a wi-fi router, which is what I've been trying to configure the IPv6 settings on.